# Apache POI test case fails as it doesn't find CTExtensionList class

Tags: java, maven, groovy, apache-poi

I have written simple groovy spock test case to validate the excel sheet. Here is in my then section I have the following.

```
then:"Should return the excel work book"

workbook != null
workbook.getNumberOfSheets() == 3
def sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
def row = sheet.getRow(4).getCell(0)
def cell = row.getCell(0);
cell.cellValue
println cell
```

I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtensionList` while accessing cell values like `cell.cellValue`.

Can you please let me know what is the issue here ?

Looking at jar poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.jar, this class is not available. Is the class not available in poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.jar or we have to refer other jar ?

Also, by looking at this link [APACHE POI](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025), I understand that we need full jar which is a size of 15 MB. How can I get it with maven ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [this Apache POI FAQ Entry](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025), the `poi-ooxml-schemas` jar only contains the most common parts of the OOXML Schemas. If you need to use any outside the common set, you have to grab the full OOXML Schemas jar, currently `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar`

As explained [in that FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025) and the [POI Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), as a maven user you'd do that with a dependency like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have added the dependency in pom.
`<!-- Apache POI dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.14</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.14</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
   <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Getting the exception

Comment: Exception is :

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setLoadEntityBytesLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
 at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:50)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(XSSFWorkbook.java:425)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:227)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:218)

Comment: Looks like you have an old copy of xmlbeans on your classpath. Remove any old ones, so you just have the POI-supplied xmlbeans 2.6

Comment: I will try that once.

Comment: btw, what dependencies I can maintain along with ooxml-schemas.? Can I have poi, poi-ooxml dependencies ?

Comment: It's [all documented on the Apache POI components page!](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)